# Magento2 Circular Depedency when reading config

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I cannot use `ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig` when extending certain objects

di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog" type="Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog" />

<virtualType name="helper" type="Foo\Log\Helper\Data" />

       <type name="Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog">
          <arguments>
             <argument name="helper" xsi:type="object">Foo\Log\Helper\Data</argument>
          </arguments>
       </type>
```

FooLog.php

```
    public function __construct(
     \Foo\Log\Helper\Data $dataHelper
   )
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
```

Data.php

```
public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
{
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/foo_bar_config', 'default');
```

Error:

```
Circular dependency: Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped depends on Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped and vice versa.
```

I can't even get existing configs like in CreateOrder.php

```
 $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_PATH_MERCHANT_ID, $this->sessionQuote->getStoreId());
```

The issue is, that using `ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig` is only not possible to use for certain objects, if I try to extend some other objects like

```
 <preference for="Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index" type="Foo\Log\Helper\Data" />
```

it works

***UPDATE**

Tried with proxy class - success

```
<type name="Foo\Log\Helper\Data">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configinterface" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface\Proxy</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Data.php

```
        public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface\Proxy $scopeConfig)
            {
                $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
               $host =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/remote_server_host');
               // error after getValue
            }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your error message is:

> Circular dependency: Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped depends on Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped and vice versa.

To understand what happens you should look at class from error message: `Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped`

In its constructor we see a dependency on `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`

As we can see in your di.xml you create a *preference* for `Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog`:
`<preference for="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog" type="Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog"/>`

`Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog` is a preference for `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface` itself. So you effectively create a preference for `\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface`, and your `Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog` will be provided to constructor of `\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped` whenever it's created.

Now if we look deeper at implementation of `ScopeConfigInterface` requested by your helper, we will see that it depends on `\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped`.

So we got into situation when to create `\Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog` we need instance `ScopedConfigInterface`, and to create `ScopedConfigInterface` we need `\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped` that requires `\Foo\Log\Logger\FooLog`: circular dependency.

To resolve this you should either not use `ScopeConfigInterface` in your helper or substitute it with [`Proxy`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html) (lazy object loading) to break circular dependency.

We will think about better circular dependency detection algorithm that will display more informative messages.

Comment: wow, this is a super clear explanation
thanks a lot for this.
To solve this:
a) is there another way to get values from admin backend without using ScopeConfigInterface?
b) I think I do not fully get the grasp of the Proxy thing
Do I need to use ScopeConfigInterface\Proxy in my helper or what is the meaning of this?

So when I like to use a config from the backend, what would be the prefered way to handle this?

Comment: Added link to proxy/lazy-loading documentation in the answer

Comment: thanks. one last thing, would you suggest to use a proxy or to avoid using scopeconfiginterface and use some other method instead?

Comment: Use a proxy for ScopeConfigInterface to avoid ScopeConfigInterface instantiation during logger instantiation

Comment: I used the proxy for ScopeConfigInterface but this seems not to fix this, please see my latest update

Answer (score 2):

in di.xml you may use preferences or virtual type tag which make circular dependence check on di.xml

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already used a preference. It is just not working within my own module somehow