# unable to serialize value string is corrupted in magento2 (update command not working )

Tags: magento2

Hi i am trying to run upgrade command but it is giving me this error and due to this error my admin panel and front end both are showing error to run upgrade command, whenever i run this command :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

it gives me error on cmd :

[image]

Although i am in developer mode and already run di:compile command many times along with cleaning cache,
can anyone guide me please what's creating issue and quick solution to fix it ,Thanks.

----------------edit --------------

### i have pasted following code in json.php

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->serialize($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}

public function serialize($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

i search it on internet its because of older version issue , i am currently using 2.2.0 magento version. but still getting another error

Comment: which magento version you are using ?

Comment: its 2.2.0 version sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but problem may be in your module **Vnecoms_SmsTeleSign**

As per Magento 2.2 Release Note

> Security enhancements
>
> In general, we’ve removed serialize/unserialize from most the code to improve protection against remote code execution attacks. We’ve enhanced protection of code where use of object serialization or unserialization was unavoidable. Additionally, we’ve increased our use of output escaping to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

So you need to inject **\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json** class for serialize and unserialize values.

use following code for serialize and unserialize values.

```
protected $serialize;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize
) {
    $this->serialize = $serialize;
}

public function serialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->serialize($value);
}

public function unserialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->unserialize($value);
}
```

Comment: its giving me following error sir : when run flush command                                                                              (Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json depends on Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json and vice versa.)

Comment: Try to use **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Comment: its giving me same error

Comment: i figured out there were unknown comma in constructor , after removing it ,error is same (Circular dependency)

Comment: Put more info like file path where are you injecting this class etc.

Comment: check [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/magento2-circular-depedency-when-reading-config) it may help you to get resolve.