# After upgrade magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 getting error : Unable to unserialize value

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.2

After upgrade magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.2 getting error :  Unable to unserialize value.

```
   Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

   Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] 
   (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. at /home/prabhsim/public_html/grittyearth.com/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value

Comment: I hope [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208179/unable-to-serialize-value-string-is-corrupted-in-magento2-update-command-not-wo/208186#208186) help you.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this issue, Override following file To solve this,

> \vendor\magento\framework\Serialize\Serializer\json.php

and replace the below function in the file.

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}

function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Source: https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/

Comment: I have already tried this but not working. after doing this i have cleared cache also.

Comment: Please run this command - php bin/mangento setup:upgrade

Comment: Delete generation, clear cache and make sure that you use \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null, class in your constructor and try again

Comment: still not working.   is there any mistake in my string. ===> String : a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:"type";s:50:"Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine";s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:9:"new_child";s:0:"";]s:4:"1--1";a:4:[s:4:"type";s:50:"Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product";s:9:"attribute";s:12:"category_ids";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";s:1:"2";]]

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, has this beeen solved ?

Comment: @David In most cases, This solution solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any mistake in my code ?
Here is my code:

```
    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

    /**
     * Serialize data to JSON, unserialize JSON encoded data
     *
     * @api
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    class Json implements SerializerInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @since 100.2.0
         */

        public function __construct(){
            $serializer = null;
        }

        public function serialize($data)
        {
            $result = json_encode($data);
            if (false === $result) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to serialize value.');
            }
            return $result;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @since 100.2.0
         */
       public function unserialize($string)
    {
        if($this->is_serialized($string))
        {
            $string = $this->serialize($string);
        }
        echo "String : ".$string. "<br>";
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        //echo "<br>Result : ".$result; die;

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

        }
        return $result;
    }

    function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
    {
        // Bit of a give away this one
        if (!is_string($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
        // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
        // false, eliminate that possibility.
        if ($value === 'b:0;')
        {
            $result = false;
            return true;
        }
        $length = strlen($value);
        $end    = '';
        switch ($value[0])
        {
            case 's':
                if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            case 'b':
            case 'i':
            case 'd':
                // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
                $end .= ';';
            case 'a':
            case 'O':
                $end .= '}';
                if ($value[1] !== ':')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                switch ($value[2])
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            case 'N':
                $end .= ';';
                if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
        {
            $result = null;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question. Don't add as answer.