# How to fix serialize error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.0

I am getting this error in magento 2. Please help me to solve this issue.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error:  - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error:  - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

## 0 E:\xampp\htdocs\best4balls\Construction\Code\vendor\magento\framework\App\PageCache\Kernel.php(153): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize(Array)

## 1 E:\xampp\htdocs\best4balls\Construction\Code\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin.php(96): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))

## 2 E:\xampp\htdocs\best4balls\Construction\Code\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))

strong text

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212333/after-upgrade-magento-2-1-8-to-2-2-2-getting-error-unable-to-unserialize-value/212335#212335

Comment: Are you getting error in custom module ?

Comment: Are you getting this issue after upgrade ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting this error in my custom module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this from custom module Please check following answer.

As per Magento 2.2 Release Note

> Security enhancements
>
> In general, we’ve removed serialize/unserialize from most the code to improve protection against remote code execution attacks. We’ve enhanced protection of code where use of object serialization or unserialization was unavoidable. Additionally, we’ve increased our use of output escaping to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

So you need to inject **\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json** class for serialize and unserialize values.

use following code for serialize and unserialize values.

```
protected $serialize;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize
) {
    $this->serialize = $serialize;
}

public function serialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->serialize($value);
}

public function unserialize($value){
    return $this->serialize->unserialize($value);
}
```