# I am getting this error on my magento store in Admin

Tags: magento2

> Uncaught LogicException: Circular dependency: Magento\Logging\Model\Handler\Controllers depends on Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone and vice versa

Comment: you clear your cache and var/generation directory after updating to latest code base?

Comment: yup alll done .but still error

Comment: check this :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/magento2-circular-depedency-when-reading-config